# gitlab commit via cURL with PHP fails

Tags: php, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to do a commit to a gitlab repository via the gitlab API and PHP. Although the payload looks fine to me, the cURL request fails and returns

```
[error] => branch_name is missing, commit_message is missing, actions is missing
```

My code looks like the following:

```
$ch_git = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx')); 
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/xxx/repository/commits'); 
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$info = array(
    'id' => 'xxx',
    'branch_name' => 'master',
    'commit_message' => 'updating content...',
    'actions' => array(
        'action' => 'update', 
        'file_path' => 'filename',
        'content' => 'test 1234'
    )
);

$payload = json_encode($info, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo '<pre>';
echo $payload;
echo '</pre>';

curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

$res = curl_exec($ch_git);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($res));
echo '</pre>';
```

As far as I can see, my payload is formatted like in [the example](https://gitlab.com/help/api/commits.md#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions), but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: There are a few things worth trying, start with setting a custom request via curl -> `curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");` and also specifying your content type as `application/json` within the headers -> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx', 'Content-Type: application/json');`. I assume the headers will be your issue as in the example you linked, they also set the header (*`--header "Content-Type: application/json"`*).

Comment: Addind the content-type did indeed change something. Now I get an error 500. Better than before. :-)

Comment: Haha whoops! On your end or theirs? ;-P

Comment: My curl_exec returns the 500, so it´s something about that.

Comment: It might be `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, just remove it for now and test!

Comment: Did not change anything. I´ll go to bed for the moment and have another look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

`actions` does not simply expect a single array but an array of arrays which then contain the single actions that shall be executed to the repository.

I furthermore found out, that the `id` parameter is optional, as I have already specified the id in the `CURLOPT_URL` parameter.

So for updating a single file in the specified repository, this code works:

```
$info = array(
   'branch_name' => 'master',
   'commit_message' => 'updating content...',
   'actions' => array(
      array(
         'action' => 'update', 
         'file_path' => 'filename',
         'content' => 'test 1234'
      )
   )
);
```